# Add add to google map and then search on it

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am new in google maps and google maps api 
i want to know how my android app add data to google maps "like location"
and then other user can get this location on the nearest search request
in other words

My app will allow people to add their location to my google map and Allowing to users  searching by location to nearest locations added by other users  not only google places library 
So the app can get json file contain the  the nearest locations around the user location

How i can do that with Google API?

Comment: If you want to display a google map view in your app you need to use google API

Comment: I don't want that 
i want to get nearest place list form google map and use it within my app

Answer (score 0):

May Help

```
// Fetches all places from GooglePlaces AutoComplete Web Service
private class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... place) {
        // For storing data from web service
        String data = "";

        // Obtain browser key from https://code.google.com/apis/console
        String key = "key=key";

        String input="";

        try {
            input = "input=" + URLEncoder.encode(place[0], "utf-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }       


        // place type to be searched
        String types = "types=geocode";

        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";         

        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = input+"&"+types+"&"+sensor+"&"+key;

        // Output format
        String output = "json";

        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/"+output+"?"+parameters;

        try{
            // Fetching the data from web service in background
            data = downloadUrl(url);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
        }
        return data;        
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {           
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        // Creating ParserTask
        parserTask = new ParserTask();

        // Starting Parsing the JSON string returned by Web Service
        parserTask.execute(result);
    }       
}


/** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String,String>>>{

    JSONObject jObject;

    @Override
    protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {            

        List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;

        PlaceJSONParser placeJsonParser = new PlaceJSONParser();

        try{
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

            // Getting the parsed data as a List construct
            places = placeJsonParser.parse(jObject);

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
        }
        return places;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) {            

            String[] from = new String[] { "description"};
            int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

            // Creating a SimpleAdapter for the AutoCompleteTextView            
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), result, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, from, to);             

            // Setting the adapter
            atvPlaces.setAdapter(adapter);
    }           
}
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Comment: That is good :)
but i need to save my app users places and then retrieve the nearest list around specific address "user location"